# Unable to install chrome extension on Windows; Also unable to install "Chrome for business and education"

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Actually my requirement is an enterprise installation of Chrome Extension automatically over 1000s of Windows machines.

I tried to install manually in my machine. I have setup the update_url in registry but I am not finding it in Chrome://extensions. For which I found around Stackoverflow that the local installation of extensions is prohibited, rather the package has to come through Web Store.

Well, so I am tried to follow, Installation of Extensions automatically, in Chrome Development Guide
@ https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iu6I0MhyrvyS5h5re5ai8RSVO2sYx2gWI4Zk4Tp6fgc/edit#heading=h.op2l1nosq8x7

Which suggested to use Chrome for Business and directed me to the link
@ https://enterprise.google.com/chrome/chrome-browser/

But the bundle is not installing. It is throwing error as attached
[Chrome Bundle installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiqtZ.png)

Please help me
- Install Chrome bundle
- or Install extension automatically (other than through Web Store)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that an enterprise install is a requirement.

However, AFAIK you can't set policies in the local registry - those will be ignored. Don't quote me on that though..

- Computer must be joined to a Windows domain.
- Configuration needs to come from domain policies as described in [ExtensionInstallForcelist](https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist).

You can check whether this policy is loaded from `chrome://policy`

Note that you haven't provided a snippet of your registry with the setting.

---

I'm afraid that errors with the installer (especially so generic-sounding) are off-topic here; you can try other StackExchange sites:

- [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (for installation errors)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) (for deployment questions)